# How can I connect multiple vertices?

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to connect multiple vertices together and make a mesh out of it. Do you have any idea why some vertices don't turn into a mesh but get this gray color?

Any tips? thx

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those aren't vertices, they're faces and it's difficult to say without seeing your blend file which you can share here https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: This question would be much easier to understand if you showed us clearly _which_ vertices (before the attempted fill) ,  and you told us _how_ you attempted to fill between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh of your model has a few problems. There are

- duplicated vertices
- overlapping faces
- overlapping edges
- flipped normals/faces

You can see the problems better when you activate the *Face Orientation Overlay* and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image: face orientation overlay]

As you can see now there are

1. gaps
2. curved overlapping edges
3. poles with more than 5 edges
4. visible orange edges (overlapping edges)

[image: problems]

**How to Fix It**

In *Edit* mode

- select everything <kbd>A</kbd> and delete all faces (<kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete > Only Faces*)
- select everything <kbd>A</kbd> and merge vertices (<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge > By Distance*)
- re-create the faces.

  - select 4 vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create the new face.
  - if the face is red, you can flip it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Normals > Flip*.
  - if the direction of the edge flow is clear, it is also sufficient to select only 2 vertices in the direction (or the edge) and press <kbd>F</kbd>. In most cases, another press on the <kbd>F</kbd> key creates the next face. The "loop" part of your model can be filled quickly by spamming <kbd>F</kbd>.
- To maintain a quad mesh topology you need to add a few more edges here and there. You can subdivide an edge (menu *Mesh > Edge > Subdivide*) or cut the face with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>).
  [image: screenshot]
- remove the overlapping edges (one at the top, another one at the bottom)
  [image: screenshot 2]

Comment: got it, thx a lot